# How to synchronize two textboxes in a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, textbox

I am trying to update two textboxes on my code, textbox1 used for information of a 'student' class property (age), textbox2 used for update the student age. 
After I synchronize, I need to update the class.

The output process is demonstrated here, in this image: 
[image]

```js
<script>

var n = -1;
var txtbox;
var example1 = '{ "students" : [' +
  '{ "First Name":"David" , "Last Name":"Berman", "Age":18 },' +
  '{ "First Name":"Anna" , "Last Name":"Smith", "Age":27 },' +
  '{ "First Name":"Peter" , "Last Name":"Jones", "Age":23 } ]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(example1); // backup

// alternative
var example2 = {
  "students": [{
      "First Name": "David",
      "Last Name": "Berman",
      "Age": 18
    },
    {
      "First Name": "Anna",
      "Last Name": "Smith",
      "Age": 27
    },
    {
      "First Name": "Peter",
      "Last Name": "Jones",
      "Age": 23
    }
  ]
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log(obj);
  $.each(obj["students"], function(i, o) {
    var opt = $("<option/>");
    $(opt).val(i);
    $(opt).text(o["First Name"] + " " + o["Last Name"]);
    $("#selStudents").append(opt);



  })

  $("#selStudents").change(function() {
    n = parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").val());
    var student = obj["students"][n];
    var s = "";
    for (var propertyName in student) {

      s += "<div><label>" + propertyName + ":" + "</label><input value='" + student[propertyName] + "'/></div>";


    }

    $("#selctedData").html(s);
    $("#inpAge").val(student.Age);
    $("#monitor").html(student.ToHTMLString());

  })


})


function GetNewAge() {
  var newAge = $("#inpAge").val();

  if (n != -1) {
    //var student = obj["students"][n];
    var student = example2;
    for (var propertyName in student) {}

    student["Age"] = newAge;
    //document.write(student["Age"]);
  } else {
    document.write("Age not exist!");

  }

}

function Reset() {

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="" style="width:400px;margin:30px auto">
    <div style="float:left">
        <select id="selStudents" multiple></select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px; position:absolute; top:30px; left: 500px; " id="selctedData" >
        select student ..
    </div>

    <div style="width:400px;margin:30px auto; position:absolute; top:100px;">
        <input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="inpAge" />
        <button onclick="GetNewAge()">Update</button>
        <button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
        <div id="monitor"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The problematic lines in code is where:  $("#selStudents").change(function () 
I created the textbox1 in this line. 
I have no idea how to connect it to textbox2 which created here the body.

So when I press on the update button, the program will take the value from textbox2 and paste it on textbox1. 
In addition, it will be required to save this info into 'example2'.

My code is using this file - 'student.js', I will publish it if it will be required.

I am pretty sure that I need to solve the problem inside the function: 'GetNewAge'.

Any help will be appreciated!

Haim

Comment: There are several issues. The WORST is the document.write. NEVER document.write after the page has loaded. Use `$("#someContainer").html(....)` instead

Comment: You likely want to give the input a a class and do something like `$("#selctedData").on("input",".inputClass",function() { $("#inpAge").val(this.value)});`

Comment: We really need a [mcve]  - you have too much code in your question now. I made you a snippet so you can see how to do that

Comment: Please use the `[<>]` snippet editor to show code that runs

Comment: People, I AM BEGINNER!!!!

Comment: Don`t kill me please!